# Access Find Previous Record using a SubQuery in a calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a sheet in excel that I converted into a table in MS Access. I need to find the previous value of a field (job) to compare to the current value and do the following calculation in my calculated field (TotalCost)

[image: Comparing Job in TotalCost]

All I'm doing is adding the cost of previous operations to determine the total cost for a job at that operation.

How can I do this in access?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate `totalcost` using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*;
       (select sum(t2.cost)
        from t as t2
        where t2.job = t.job and t2.operation <= t.operation
       ) as totalcost
from t;
```

Comment: I fixed the format but it still gives me the wrong values since there's no if statement in there comparing job numbers. See the highlighted excel formula

Comment: @kingehp . . . The logic compares the job numbers.